# How to create re-usable mocks in mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Say I want to create use `sinon.stub` to mock an object:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    this.someMethod = stub(SomeObject, 'someMethod');
});

afterEach(() => {
    this.someMethod.restore();
});
```

How can I move this code into a re-usable mock file so that I can include it in every test where the `SomeObject` needs to be mocked?

Comment: Make base test class with test context, make beforeEach in it - running through test context actions and executing them. Your code is one of actions.

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin sorry what?! Did not understand that at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating `hooks` to pass into my functions:

```
// SomeObjectMock

export function beforeEachHook(SomeObject) {
   return function() {
      this.someMethod = stub(SomeObject, 'someMethod');
   }.bind(this);
}

export function afterEachHook() {
    return function() {
       this.someMethod.restore();
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Then in my test file:

```
import {afterEachHook, beforeEachHook} from './SomeObjectMock';

describe('myTest', () => {
   beforeEach(beforeEachHook.bind(this)(SomeObject));
   afterEach(afterEachHook.bind(this)());
});
```